# Using VisualSVN with edited host file

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I am receiving an error when trying to get a solution from subversion.

Here are the step I took:

1. I edited the host file located here C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
2. I added the the line 111.222.333.444 DEV.test.local
3. In VS 2010 I chose Get Solution from Subversion
4. I enter DEV.test.local/svn/Project1/trunk
5. I enter me credntials (I know these credentials are fine bc i have used them before)
6. I recieve this error: OPTIONS of 'https://DEV.test.local/svn/Project1/trunk': authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge (https://DEV.test.local)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.)** Make sure the changes were actually saved to the ../etc/hosts file because it is naturally "read-only" and must be changed with Administrator access.
  - Also, make sure the line is not commented out with a "#" at the beginning.

**2.)** Assuming the changes to the "Hosts" file on your workstation are correct, does a ping test to "dev.test.local" resolve "111.222.333.444"?

Try

```
 - "ipconfig /flushdns"
```

and/or other commands to reset your network interface, if it does not resolve the IP.

**3.)** Are your credentials taking Domains or Workgroups into account?

**4.)** Check any recent changes to firewalls or network settings on both machines.

Comment: It resolves to the correct ip. No D/W with login. I dropped my firewall and attempted again with the same results.